# How do I remove the Advanced Menu module from Orchard?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, module, compiler-errors, orchardcms

It seems that Piotr's Advanced Menu is release in parallel with the version of Orchard. I say this because I just installed the Advanced Menu 1.4.1 module to Orchard 1.3.10. And now I get this message:

> Error compiling module "Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu" from file "/orchard/Modules/Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu/Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu.csproj":
>   The assembly reference 'Orchard.Autoroute' could not be loaded.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Advanced Menu >=1.4 will **only** work with Orchard >=1.4.

*Unfortunately, there were some breaking changes in Orchard core, that make it impossible to maintain the module's backward compatibility.*

I'd advise you to restore the previous menu version and stick to that until you upgrade your instance to 1.4. Then, you can update the module.

If you updated the module from Orchard admin, there is a _Backup folder in /Modules that keeps the old code for updated modules. Just replace the entire /Modules/Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu with the one found in backup folder.

Comment: Well this was the first time I've used your module, so just before you replied, I cut and pasted the folder from the Modules folder to the Desktop. And everything seemed fine. Was that good or bad?

Comment: Yes that's ok, the simplest solution is to just remove the whole folder:) Orchard dynamically compiles modules, so if it's not there it won't try to compile it (and error won't be thrown) and everything will be fine.